# Getting exif data from all images in a directory using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm pretty new to Python and I am trying to write a script which will extract the exif data from all the images in a directory (and then do further "stuff" with the dictionary it creates).  I'm using Python 2.7 as it needs to work with ArcPy.

I am trying to avoid having to install things using pip as it will be being used by users who can't do such things (network security) and I have found exifread does what I want with just one file, I just need for it to do it with more.

So far the script I have is as follows:

```
import os
import exifread

# Select the directory which the image files are in

dircont = raw_input("Please select the directory which you wish to retrieve geotags from ")

# Get the list of image files
directory = os.listdir(dircont)
for files in directory:
if files.endswith ('.jpg'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
if files.endswith ('.JPG'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
if files.endswith ('.png'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
if files.endswith ('.PNG'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
if files.endswith ('.tiff'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
if files.endswith ('.TIFF'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path  


# EXIFREAD CODE
# Open image file for reading (binary mode)

f = open(file_path, 'rb')

# Return Exif tags
tags = exifread.process_file(f)

for tag in tags.keys():
    if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
        print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you write this:

```
if files.endswith (('jpg','JPG','png','PNG','tiff','TIFF')):
   file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
   print file_path
   #Exifread magic
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was being a bit slow but I have found the answer to my own question.  Posting here to help any other newbies out.  Basically I just had to put the exifread code as part of my if statements:

```
# Select the directory which the image files are in
dircont = raw_input("Please select the file which you wish to retrieve geotags from ")

# Get the list of image files in the directory that exifread supports
directory = os.listdir(dircont)
for files in directory:
if files.endswith ('.jpg'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
if files.endswith ('.JPG'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
if files.endswith ('.png'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
if files.endswith ('.PNG'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
if files.endswith ('.tiff'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
if files.endswith ('.TIFF'):
    file_path = os.path.join(dircont, files)
    print file_path
    #Exifread magic
    f = open(file_path, 'rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    for tag in tags.keys():
        if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
            print "Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import exifread
import os,sys
dircont = input("Please Enter the path of your directory ")
directory = os.listdir(dircont)
for files in directory:
    if files.endswith (('jpg','JPG','png','PNG','tiff','TIFF')):
        file_path = os.path.join(dircont, fil)
        print (file_path)
        f = open(file_path, 'rb')
        tags = exifread.process_file(f)
        for tag in tags.keys():
            if tag not in ('JPEGThumbnail', 'TIFFThumbnail', 'Filename', 'EXIF MakerNote'):
                print ("Key: %s, value %s" % (tag, tags[tag]))
```